# I want to get the array count on based of few conditions

Tags: javascript

I have the following result from an API

```
data: {
    "total_slots": int,
    "occupied_count": int,
    "occupied_slots" : [int] e.g.[452,453,459] (here each int in the array signfies an occupied slot),
    "slots_down" : [int] e.g.[460,462] (here each int in the array signfies a down slot)
}
```

I want the following conditions

```
VAR OCCUPIED, length of the list which are occupied minus length of common slots in occupied and slots_down
VAR TOTAL_SLOTS = total slots (which are 31 i think) - slots which are down
VAR AVAILABLE = (31 - length(slots_down)) - length( slots occupied AND not down)
```

The slots are 31 that are fixed.

```
var ALL_SLOTS = [452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523];
```

How can I meet the OR/AND conditions like `VAR AVAILABLE = (31 - length(slots_down)) - length( slots occupied AND not down)`

**This is my CURRENT CODE**

```
s = JSON.parse(s);
console.log(s);
SLOTS_DOWN = s.slots_down;
var total_slots = s.total_slots;
SLOTS_DOWN = s.slots_down.length;
console.log('down slots are ' + SLOTS_DOWN);
total_slots = parseInt(total_slots) - parseInt(SLOTS_DOWN);
var occupied = s.occupied_count;
var available = parseInt(total_slots) - parseInt(occupied) - parseInt(SLOTS_DOWN);
```

Comment: what is `slots_down`?

Comment: Will need an array of slots_down too.

Comment: A user with your rep should know the importance of sharing code

Comment: @dev8080 already done but currently it is not handling the slots_down thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to these:

> VAR OCCUPIED, length of the list which are occupied minus length of common 
>      slots in occupied and slots_down
>      VAR TOTAL_SLOTS = total slots (which are 31 i think) - slots which are down
>      VAR AVAILABLE = (31 - length(slots_down)) - length( slots occupied AND not down)

you could try this:

```
var OCCUPIED = data.occupied_count -
          data.occupied_slots.filter(function(elem){
                                       return data.slots_down.indexOf(elem)>-1;
                 }).length;

var TOTAL_SLOTS = data.total_slots.length - data.slots_down.length;


var AVAILABLE = ((data.total_slots.length - data.slots_down.length)) - 
            data.occupied_slots.filter(function(elem){
            return data.slots_down.indexOf(elem)==-1;
       }).length
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
    data = {
        "total_slots": 124,
        "occupied_count": 3,
        "occupied_slots" : [245, 326, 256],
        "slots_down" : [245, 136]
    }
    var down_but_not_occ = 0;
    data.slots_down.map(function(v, i){
        if(data.occupied_slots.indexOf(v) === -1){
               down_but_not_occ ++;
        };
    })

    var available_slots = parseInt(data.total_slots) - data.occupied_slots.length - down_but_not_occ;
    console.log(available_slots);
```

Where you were wrong,

```
total_slots = parseInt(total_slots) - parseInt(SLOTS_DOWN); // slots down subtracted
var occupied = s.occupied_count;
var available = parseInt(total_slots) - parseInt(occupied) - parseInt(SLOTS_DOWN); // slots down AGAIN subtracted
```

Comment: what about the occupied and total slots?